# how to make a specific if for string java

Tags: java, if-statement

for example i have a data :

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> lastdata A with B

I want to create an additional comment for everyline like

> A | this is A
>
> B | this is B
>
> C | this is C
>
> lastdata A with B | this is A and B

right now I tried to do manually if like this

```
 if(line.contains( "A")){
                updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "this is A");
            }
```

but I can't using contains method when I want to do the 'A with B' because it will automatically use 'this is A' comment, so what should I do to create the specific comment like that?

note: the real data I used have 5000k lines++, so if someone know anyway without do manually like this, its really help

Comment: What about `if (line.equals("A"))`?

Comment: `if(line.contains("A") && line.contains("B"))`

Comment: Do you only have A, B and C, eventually combined as X with Y, or are there other expressions?

Comment: I have another expression, this is only an example, and I can't use equals method because sometimes I need to add same comment for different data, eg: A,1_A_1,R-A will get 'this is A' comment

Comment: If I understand well, you want to check whether the expression contains A, B and/or C? Is it possible all three are present? If so, what's the desired output?

Comment: thats gonna be 'this is A, B, and C'

Comment: No other letters than A, B and C?

Comment: there are, I only put some example here, because if I put all of them, its gonna be too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
if (line.contains("A") && !line.contains("B")) {
    updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "this is A");
}

if (line.contains("B") && !line.contains("A")) {
    updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "this is B");
}

if (line.contains("A") && line.contains("B")) {
    updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "this is A with B");
}
```

one more example

```
String result = line + " | this is " + Stream.of("A", "B", "C")
        .filter(line::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" with "));
updatedLines.add(result);
```

Comment: this is works actually, but is there another option?

Comment: ofc, you have a lot of options

Comment: added one more example how you can do this

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one line which starts with "lastdata" you can simply put this condition first like

```
 If(line.startsWith("lastdata")
     updatedLines.add(line + "|" + line.replace("lastdata", "this is"));
 else
     updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "this is "+line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to handle this is to use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) you can do something like :

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" and ");

if (line.contains("A")) {
    sj.add("A");
}
if (line.contains("B")) {
    sj.add("B");
}
...
if (sj.length() > 0) {
    updatedLines.add(line + " | this is " + sj.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your String into Char array then do what you want to each Character in a string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testStr = "ABC";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] arrStr = testStr.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0){
            sb.append(testStr + "| This is " + arrStr[i]);
        } else {
            sb.append(" And " + arrStr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit old-fashioned, but the thing I tried works:

```
public class TestPattern
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Scanner scanner;
      String  line;
      scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      for (;;)
      {
        System.out.print("Enter line: ");
        System.out.flush();
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty())
          break;
        check(line);
      }
      scanner.close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception_ipar)
    {
      exception_ipar.printStackTrace();
    }

  } // main

  public static void check(String line)
  {
    // ----------------------------------
    // Determine patterns present in line
    // ----------------------------------
    List<String>     found;
    Iterator<String> it;
    String           pattern;
    found = new ArrayList<String>();
    it = patterns.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
      pattern = it.next();
      if (line.contains(pattern))
        found.add(pattern);
    }

    // -------------------
    // Maybe nothing found
    // -------------------
    if (found.isEmpty())
    {
      System.out.println("No pattern found");
      return;
    }

    // --------------
    // Compose result
    // --------------
    StringBuilder result;
    int           counter;
    result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(line + " | ");
    for (counter = 0; counter < found.size(); counter++)
    {
      if (counter == 0)
        result.append("this is ");
      else if (counter == (found.size() - 1))
        result.append(" and ");
      else
        result.append(", ");
      result.append(found.get(counter));
    }

    // -----------
    // Show result
    // -----------
    System.out.println(result);

  } // check

  private static Set<String> patterns;

  static
  {
    patterns = new TreeSet<String>();
    patterns.add("A");
    patterns.add("B");
    patterns.add("C");
  }

} // class TestPattern
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper class where you can register what you want to check for and let it build the comment for you

```
public class CommentAppender
{
    private ArrayList<String> tokens;
    private boolean orderMatters = false;

    public CommentAppender()
    {
        this(false);
    }

    public CommentAppender(bool orderMatters)
    {
        tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        this.orderMatters = orderMatters;
    }

    public void registerToken(String tok)
    {
        tokens.add(tok);
    }

    public String generateCommentForInput(String input)
    {
        ArrayList<String> matchedTokens = new ArrayList<>();

        int offset = 0;

        for(String tok : tokens)
        {
            int io = input.indexOf(tok, offset);
            if(io != -1)
            {
                matchedTokens.add(tok);
                offset = orderMatters? io + 1 : 0;
            }
        }

        // Build the comment
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(matchedTokens.size() > 0)
        {
            sb.append("this is ");
            sb.append(matchedTokens.get(0));
            for(int i = 1; i < matchedTokens.size(); i++)
            {   
                sb.append(" and ");
                sb.append(matchedTokens.get(1));
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}

CommentAppender ca = new CommentAppender();
ca.registerToken("A");
ca.registerToken("B");
ca.registerToken("C");
```